# Validation doesn't work when I test using MockMvc

Tags: spring, mockmvc

I'm trying to create a Rest API using the Spring framework. I am using @Valid annotation using Hibernate-Validator to validate the server request values.

To test this, I am using MockMvc. However, when I request a value to that address in MockMvc, the validation doesn't work.

If I run my local server without testing and check it, it works fine.

I've tried debugging and it doesn't load the Validator to do the validation, how can I fix this?

The other posts are using boot, but I'm not using spring boot. Isn't the framework in spring boot the same thing, or is there something different?

Here are the annotations I used for testing.
`@WebAppConfiguration @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) @ContextConfiguration`

**Solution**

Change any applicable dependency versions to the latest version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add a dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Spring Framework 5.3.21 with Bean Validation 2.0.1 and Hibernate Validator 6.0.23, there shouldn't be any compatibility issues that would prevent validation from working with MockMvc. However, there might be other reasons why the validation is not working in your test environment.

Here are a few additional steps you can try to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Check Test Configuration: Make sure that your test class is properly configured with the necessary annotations. Ensure that you have the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation at the class level and the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation specifying your configuration class.
2. Use `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup`: Instead of using `webAppContextSetup`, try using `standaloneSetup` to configure your `MockMvc`. This method sets up MockMvc without loading the entire Spring context, which could potentially help resolve the issue.

```java
@Before
public void setup() {
    YourController yourController = new YourController();
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new YourExceptionHandler()) // If applicable
            .build();
}
```

Ensure that you replace `YourController` with the appropriate controller class that you want to test.

3. Verify Validator Setup: Double-check that your validation setup is correct. Ensure that you have properly annotated your request parameters or request bodies with validation annotations from Hibernate Validator, such as `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty`, or `@Valid`.
4. Test Case for Validation Failure: Create a specific test case where you intentionally send an invalid request and verify that the validation error is returned. For example:

```java
@Test
public void testInvalidRequest() throws Exception {
    YourRequestObject invalidRequest = new YourRequestObject();
    // Set invalid values on the request object...

    mockMvc.perform(post("/your-endpoint")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(invalidRequest)))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errors", hasSize(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errors[0]", containsString("Your validation error message")));
}
```

Ensure that you customize the assertions to match your expected validation error response.

5. Dependency Conflict: Check your project's dependencies and make sure there are no conflicts between different versions of Hibernate Validator or other related libraries. Verify that there are no incompatible dependencies that might interfere with the validation process.
6. Upgrade Dependencies: Consider upgrading your dependencies to the latest versions. Hibernate Validator 6.1.x and Spring Framework 5.3.x are compatible, so upgrading to the latest versions might help resolve any potential issues.

If the above steps do not resolve your issue, please provide more details about your configuration, controller, and test code so that I can assist you further.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
But when I create a new project and try it, the result is the same, is there any other way?

The spring framework version is 5.3.21
Bean Validation version is 2.0.1
hibernate-validator version is 6.0.23

Comment: @BlueBear I've updated my answer. there was some code samples therefore i updated the answer. please check it

Comment: Your 8 most recent answers all appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.